# Identify Which Experiments are Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability

> Which of the following experiments are Bernoulli trials?
>
> a. A die is tossed 4 times and we record the number obtained for each trial.
>
> b. A die is tossed 4 times and we record whether or not the number obtained is odd
> for each trial.
>
> c. A box contains 4 red and 6 blue balls. A ball is picked up from the box 3 times
> with replacement.
>
> d. A box contains 4 red and 6 blue balls. A ball is picked up from the box 3 times
> without replacement.

My Work:
I know the following

Bernoulli trials (p: parameter) have the following properties:

a. Each trial yields one of two outcomes: success (S) or failure (F).

b. P(S) = p and P(F) = 1-p

c. Each trial must be independent

So using the above I said

A) Not Bernoulli Trials as although the trials are independent, there's no success or failure defined here. What number do we identify as a success? It's not given so we can't apply Bernoulli Trials here.

B) Yes, this is Bernoulli Trials as there's a definitive success (Getting a odd number) and failure (getting a even number) and the trials are independent as well!

C) No...? There's no success condition or failure condition defined here (What's a success? what's a failure?) so not Bernoulli Trials. Although they are independent trials.

D) No, same reason as C and add on the fact that the trials aren't independent as there's no replacement.

Is my reasoning/logic correct? Especially with C and D? I feel like I may be overthinking it. Any help with better identifying Bernoulli Trials in experiments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Indeed, the weird thing is that in C and D, the random variable is not even defined. So I agree with you: A is not, B is, and C and D are poorly defined.

Comment: I think it's kinda obvious that the random variable in C and D is supposed to be the color of the ball you picked. Then just pick one of the two colors as success and the other as failure. The point of a Bernoulli trial is not really that there is success and failure, but that there are exactly two possible outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, because I've never heard the phrase "Bernoulli trials".  However, I think that I can reverse engineer an answer based on the OP's work and based on Matti P.'s comment, which I **partially disagree** with.

In part b, it is apparently okay (as a matter of protocol) to arbitrarily construe an odd number as a successful event.  Based on this, I would  argue that in **both** parts c and d, it is okay to construe a **red ball** as a successful event.

Then, (again based on the OP's problem and Matti P's comment), I would distinguish between parts c and d as follows:

In part c, with the sampling done **with replacement**, the outcome of each sampling is independent of the outcome of any of the other samplings.  Based on this, I (arbitrarily, and perhaps wrongly) construe part c as a bernoulli trial.

In part d, the sampling is done **without replacement.**  This means that the outcome of each sampling is **not independent** of the outcome of the other samplings.  Therefore, based on my construance, part d is not a bernoulli trial.

**Addendum**:
I confess that I metacheated here.
I admit that the distinction between parts c and d could be a red herring, and the problem could represent a carefully constructed trap.  However, based on the OP's posting, since a core characteristic of bernoulli trials is independence, my instinct is that my construance above is intended by whoever formulated the question.